# Is it possible to call a Java function from a HANA database

Tags: java, hana

Is it possible to call a Java function from a HANA database? In my case, the Java function will take an input XML and return a formatted array output. What will the HANA SQL call look like?

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible. SQL in HANA cannot 'dial out' to JAVA.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this operation using the SQL function.
XMLTABLE:

```
 SELECT * FROM
 XMLTABLE('/doc/item' PASSING
 '<doc>
   <item><id>10</id><name>Box</name></item>
   <item><id>20</id><name>Jar</name></item>
 </doc>'
 COLUMNS 
 line_num FOR ORDINALITY,
 ID INT PATH 'id', 
 NAME VARCHAR(20) PATH 'name'
 ) as XTABLE;
```

Output:

```
| line_num  | ID   | NAME   |  
| --------- | ---- | -----  |  
|    1      | 10   | Box    |  
|    2      | 20   | Jar    |
```

Bear in mind in only works on HANA 2 SP 2.
[official doc for xmltable function](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.02/en-US/2bb8ab119e384b5f94635696bb9f68b5.html)